# "Qual o objetivo..." ou "Qual objetivo.."?

Tags: sintaxe

Fiz essa pergunta no SOpt:

> [Qual o objetivo do internal lateinit?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227752/qual-o-objetivo-do-internal-lateinit)

Aí fiquei na dúvida entre "Qual o objetivo" ou "Qual objetivo". Não sei exatamente se as duas opções estão corretas.

Qual é mais correto falar, "Qual o objetivo..." ou "Qual objetivo.."?

Comment: Em pt-PT seria «Qual é o objetivo...». Fica só para referência...

Comment: @JorgeB. também tem essa questão. No BR também falamos "Qual é o objetivo...", mas não sei exatamente se há algo errado em falar "Qual objetivo" ou "Qual o objetivo..."... na informalidade, todo mundo aqui fala de todas as formas. Mas na teoria não sei qual seria o mais correto.

Answer (score 4):

O correto é *Qual (é) o objetivo do* internal lateinit​*?*. A cópula *é* pode perfeitamente ser omitida.

*Qual objetivo* só poderia ser usado [numa réplica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-cFKV5boc0):

> — Precisa de escrever uma carta ao nosso diretor e trazer o papel.
>   — Qual papel?

Comment: Ou também poderia ser utilizado numa expressão como "Aqui estão os objetivos da pesquisa. De qual objetivo gostaste mais?"

Answer (score 1):

Gramaticalmente, as duas formas estão corretas, sendo o mais usual, tanto no português brasileiro como europeu, a supressão do "é".

Para a conversação e compreensão também não há problemas, pois a supressão do verbo não implica problemas no diálogo, visto que está implícito (tentei pensar em um exemplo onde a omissão pudesse ser sentida e não consegui).

Até mesmo o dicionário Houaiss utiliza a sentença "[Qual a sua opinião](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/qual-%C3%A9-a-sua-opini%C3%A3o.2791730/)?", sem problemas.

Pessoalmente, prefiro com o verbo "é". Preciosismo ou não, soa-me uma construção mais bonita e, inclusive, correta.